# Cmd output to file gives wrong character encoding

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, textfiles

When I redirect the `cmd` command `tree` to a text file:

```
tree > c:\tree.txt
```

and open the file with notepad I get the following result:

```
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 00000:0000
Z:.
ÃÄÄÄSome dir
³   ÃÄÄÄSome sub dir
³   ÃÄÄÄOther sub dir
³   ÀÄÄÄFoo dir 
ÃÄÄÄOther dir
```

Is it possible to open (or write) the file in such a way that the character encoding is correct?

If I output it to the console, the output looks fine.

```
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 000:000
Z:.
├───Some Dir
├───Some other dir
│   ├───Some sub dir
│   │   ├───Foo dir
etc.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chcp` gives me codepage 850 (Windows 7, German). Changing the codepage with `chcp` shows no effect for the output of `tree`.

Workaround: open the file in an editor like notepad++, select OEM 850 as encoding and convert it to i.e. UTF-8.

[image: screenshot notepad++]